# Spring Integration: Poller acting weird

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a configuration to read the data from DB using `jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter`. The configuration:

```
   <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="SELECT * FROM requests WHERE processed_status = '' OR processed_status IS NULL LIMIT 5" channel="requestsJdbcChannel"
    data-source="dataSource" update="UPDATE requests  SET processed_status = 'INPROGRESS', date_processed = NOW() WHERE id IN (:id)" >
          <int:poller fixed-rate="30000" />
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:splitter input-channel="requestsJdbcChannel" output-channel="requestsQueueChannel"/>

    <int:channel id="requestsQueueChannel">
          <int:queue capacity="1000"/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:chain id="requestsChain" input-channel="requestsQueueChannel" output-channel="requestsApiChannel"> 
          <int:poller  max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="1000" />
    .
    .
    </int:chain>
```

In the above configuration, I have defined the jdbc poller with `fixed-rate` of 30 seconds. When there is direct channel instead of `requestsQueueChannel` the select query gets only 5 rows (since I am using limiting the rows in select query) and waits for another 30 seconds for next poll.

But after I introduce `requestsQueueChannel` with queue and added poller inside `requestsChain`, the `jdbc-inbound` doesn't work as expected. It doesn't wait for another 30 second for next poll. Sometimes it polls the DB twice in a row(within a second) as if there are 2 threads running and gets two sets of rows from DB. However, there is no async handoff except these mentioned above.

My understanding is that even if there is `requestsQueueChannel`, once it executes the select query it should wait for another 30 seconds to poll the DB. Is there anything I am missing? I just want to understand the behavior of this configuration.

Comment: Given that it's happening twice, it sounds a lot like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184355/how-to-prevent-duplicate-spring-integration-service-activations-when-polling-dir

Comment: I think that is not the issue here as the direct channel don't have this problem. Moreover, it doesn't read duplicates. The poller runs in a succession instead of 30second gap.

Comment: That's exactly how pollers behave if you have accidentally loaded their config into 2 contexts (web & root). It won't load duplicates, because it's updating the `processed_status` in the database to prevent that. Are you absolutely sure that you don't have 2 contexts?

Comment: @Steve Spot on. The servlet context and root context were both loading the same integration context. Thanks Steve. Saved my day. If you can write it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Done ... glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of Spring integration pollers activating twice, as though they are 2 threads, is the basically the same problem I came across here, with file system pollers:

[How to prevent duplicate Spring Integration service activations when polling directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184355/how-to-prevent-duplicate-spring-integration-service-activations-when-polling-dir)

Apparently this is a relatively common misconfiguration, where Spring root and servlet contexts both load the Spring Integration configuration. As a result of this, there are indeed two threads, and pollers can be seen to activate twice within their polling period. Usually within a few seconds of each other, as each will start when its context loads.

My approach to ensuring that the Spring Integration configuration was only loaded in a single context was to structure the project packages to ensure separation.

First define a web config which only picks up classes under the "web" package.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp.web" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Create separate root configuration classes to load beans such as services and repositories, which do not belong in the servlet context. One of these should load the Spring Integration configuration. i.e.:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp.eip" })
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/integration-context.xml"     })
public class EipConfig {
}
```

An additional factor in the configuration that took a little while to work out, was that my servlet filters and web security config needed to be in the root context rather than the servlet context.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `DirectChannel` the next poll isn't considered until the current one ends.

When using a `QueueChannel` (or task executor), the poller is free to run again.

Inbound adapters have `max-messages-per-poll` set to 1 by default so your config should work as expected. Can you post a DEBUG log somewhere?

Comment: what is the use of `fixed-rate="30000"` then? I thought the time gap between 2 successive polls is 30seconds.

Comment: You need both the fixed-rate AND `max-messages-per-poll` by default, the poller keeps calling the source until there's no more data, then waits for the next trigger.

Comment: My mistake; `max-messages-per-poll` is set to 1 by default for inbound channel adapters. So you should not have to set it. Can you post a DEBUG log someplace?