# Spring Integration SFTP code getting called twice

Tags: java, spring-integration, jsch, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying basic spring integration to download file from SFTP.
Below is a code. The issue is that service-activator gets called twice.

In short, if you see the log, the log's in FileListener bean get called twice and also the com.jcraft.jsch logs 
get logged twice, if feel there are two sessions and hence my program is getting executed twice.

Please suggest.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">

    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="11.222.333.44" />
        <property name="user" value="*****" />
        <property name="password" value="******"></property>
        <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpadapter"
        auto-startup="true" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        channel="requestChannel" filename-pattern="*.csv" remote-directory="/someDirectory/"
        local-directory="D:\\somelocalDirectory\\"
        auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false">
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="requestChannel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel"
        ref="FileListener" method="handle" />

    <int:poller id="defaultpoller" default="true" fixed-rate="10000"
        max-messages-per-poll="1"></int:poller>

    <bean id="FileListener" class="com.somePackage.FileListener">
    </bean>
```

ANd the java code is as simple as this.

```
public class InboundFileListener2 {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(InboundFileListener2.class);

    public void handle(Message<?> message) {
        String someId = null;
        String fileName = null;

        try {

            someId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            fileName = getFilename(message);

            logger.debug(" CorrelationId : "
                    + someId + " FileName is : " + fileName);
```

Below is the log.

```
 SomeId : a77b2bc4-b874-40e7-998d-6ca17aeec196 FileName is : somefile_05032017142503.csv
 SomeId : c50a95e9-83f5-4bb8-a3d9-15da0ff553ee FileName is : somefile_05032017142503.csv
Connecting to 11.222.333.44 port 22
Connecting to 11.222.333.44 port 22
Connection established
Connection established
aes256-ctr is not available.
aes192-ctr is not available.
aes256-cbc is not available.
aes192-cbc is not available.
```

**UPDATED:**

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>some-name</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Might be your config file loaded twice? check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184355/how-to-prevent-duplicate-spring-integration-service-activations-when-polling-dir

Comment: Thanks for your swift response, I think you are very correct, But how do I separate the listeners in multiple contexts in my case. I have a dispatcher servelet as mentioned in my post. (The xml part). Please suggest.

Comment: You need to show your `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I have added the web.xml,

Comment: I feel removing servlet tag should fix it but I am not sure, if that what is correct solution. Confused.

Comment: Hi Gary, Can you please explain, why removing <servlet> tag fixed this issue, if webcontext is extension to root context why does both load the adapters in each, should't just either of them load it and use it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting below code from web.xml fixed the issue.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But I am not sure why it happened, if webcontext is just an extension to root context to load just resources for web other than root scope, either of them should load the sftp adapter and initialize it rather than both of then initializing it..... Can some please explain....